# Using Hlint with intero on emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs, hlint, intero

I can't get hlint suggestions to appear in emacs using intero.

- I have a new installation of emacs 24.5
- I added the intero stuff at [here](http://commercialhaskell.github.io/intero/) into new `~/.emacs` file
- I've done nothing else to emacs.

I've read that the solution is:

```
(flycheck-add-next-checker 'intero
                           '(warning . haskell-hlint))
```

But I don't know what I'm supposed to do with this. If I add it to my `~/.emacs` file then emacs fails on start up.

(The rest seems OK - intero starts when I open a Haskell file - errors are immediately flagged as I type.)

How do I get Hlint suggestions to appear?

Comment: Have you installed `hlint` ?

Comment: hlint is installed in my stack project, i.e. I can run `stack exec hlint` but it's not installed globally.

Comment: Can you do the following checks: 1) See if your hlint executable is in the correct path which your flycheck recognizes. Explictly add in the variable `exec-path`, if it's not in that path. I usually install hlint globally via stack and use that for my emacs session.
2) If 1st method is not the problem, then try running this emacs command: `intero-info` and then see if flycheck shows the hlint warnings for you.

Comment: And just to ask the most obvious think - does your file actually have any warnings ? :-) You can check that by running hlint manually on the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by adding this to my ~/.emacs file:

```
;; do linting on-the-fly 
(with-eval-after-load 'intero
  (flycheck-add-next-checker 'intero '(warning . haskell-hlint))
)
```

(The full ~/.emacs file can be viewed [here](https://github.com/BillyBadBoy/haskell-emacs-setup/blob/master/init.el))